# Where can I find something similar to White Chocolate Moose (Dixie Brewing Co)?

Tags: breweries, specialty-beers

[Dixie Brewing Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixie_Brewing_Company) used to make a dessert beer called White Chocolate Moose.  It was a sweet, chocolate-flavored (I don't mean chocolate malt) beer and came in small (I think 7oz) bottles -- which was the right size for something that concentrated.  (In a way, it was to beer what ice wine is to wine.)  Then Hurricane Katrina happened and the brewery was destroyed.  According to Wikipedia they operate now as a contract brewery, but as far as I can tell they're not making this particular product, at least under that name.  ("As far as I can tell": I can't find a web site for the company nor a product list, but my searches under this name aren't producing results.)

Is somebody producing this under a different name?  If so, who and where?  If not, what beers are available that are similar in taste?

Comment: https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/404/2373/.  I'm doing a bit of digging as this has intrigued me - if I find anything I will let you know ASAP.

Comment: http://www.mensjournal.com/expert-advice/the-11-best-chocolate-beers-20160205/rogue-double-chocolate-stout.  Also found this.

Answer (score 4):

There are several that you might try.

[**The Bruery**](http://www.thebruery.com/beer/white-chocolate/) White Chocolate

> This bourbon barrel-aged wheatwine-style ale made a fanciful trip to the chocolatier and returned with luscious flavors of white chocolate – hence the name. White Chocolate is a rewarding summons to the senses – beginning with its golden appearance and finishing with warming, white chocolate-like flavors. This is accomplished by adding cacao nibs from TCHO and fresh vanilla beans to our bourbon barrel-aged wheatwine-style ale, complimenting the rich notes of coconut, honey, caramel and vanilla from extensive barrel-aging.
>
> **Food Pairing**
>   Funnel cake, warm fruit cobbler, a white chocolate-and-macadamia nut ice cream sandwich. The County Fair.

**[Sonoran Brew Company](http://www.sonoranbrewing.com/beers) White Chocolate Ale**

As [Beer Advocate](https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/13564/64164/) describes it:

> Inspired by the beauty of the White Mountains; the Sonoran White Chocolate Ale is a light, refreshing and completely unique wheat beer. Like a fine chocolate, this brew has a delicate aroma and a subtle taste of white chocolate, which is truly astonishing!

Comment: Nice find, Dorothy. keep it up.

Comment: @KenGraham why am I not surprised that this site's users are so open, friendly, and mellow :-) I do participate quie a bit in SE Travel and Expats, and a careful bit in Seasoned. So slainte to you for that feedback.